# python lists and for loops to append to a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create another empty list (newlist = []) and write a second for loop that checks each element of the list to see if it is even, and if it is even, that element gets appended to newlist.
this is my code so far

```
list = []
for item in range(5):
    next = int(input("Please enter an integer value:  ")) 
list.append(next)
print list
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output (and, if needed, why the former leads to the latter) instead of a somewhat confusing description and user input code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name!

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
newlist = [i for i in mylist if i%2 == 0]
```

(don't name a variable `list`, that's already the name of a built-in function)

---

From your code, it appears that the append is not happening within the scope of the `for`-loop. You instead want:

```
for item in range(5):
    next = int(input("Please enter an integer value:  ")) 
    mylist.append(next)  # indented!
```

You can then obtain the even values via what is shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
lst = []
for item in range(5):
    next = int(input("Please enter an integer value:  ")) 
    lst.append(next)
print lst

secondlist = []
for item in list:
    if item % 2 == 0: # check if item is even
        secondlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nextlist = []

for i in list:
    if i % 2 == 0: nextlist.append(i)

print nextlist
```

Don't call your variables any reserved words, I understand you might have just named them that to show as an example but just in case you were, rename "list" and "next"